# Gaussian distribution with gaussian parameters

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(M, S)$, where $M,S$ are themselves gaussian random variable with mean $\mu_{M,S}$ and variance $\sigma_{M,S}$.
Does this distribution have a particular name/form? Can we compute its CDF?

Comment: How is $\mathcal{N}(M,S)$ defined when $S$ is negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If S is Gaussian then it could be negative which does not work.  This problem is common in Bayesian statistics. Possibly specifying the precession $=1/S^2$ will work better. It will be easy to integrate out the M, this will just give a new Gaussian where the mean depends on $\mu_M$, $S$ and $\sigma_M$. Integrating out the S will be messy and possibly not possible.